# typedef definition not found

Tags: c, typedef

I can't figure why the following code gives compilation error as if the typedef definition not found. In fact, if I add the line 'typedef TCHAR my_tchar;' (which is already in win32def.h) in app.h the compilation goes well.

win32def.h

```
#ifndef win32def_h
#define win32def_h

#include <tchar.h>

typedef TCHAR my_tchar;

#endif
```

app.h

```
#include "win32def.h"
int my_function(const my_tchar *filename, ....)
```

```
compilation error at line of my_function:

error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
```

Comment: Where is your C code? What actually is the line in the header? You haven't provided the necessary information.

Comment: Try including the header file which has TCHAR in win32def.h

Answer (score 0):

what the compiler is used?
I'm not sure, but try to turn on the option "treat wchar_t as built-in type".

Comment: It is VS 2005 C compiler. The option "treat wchar_t as built-in type" is already turned on in project settings.

Comment: maybe vice versa? (I don't have compiler to check it right now)

Comment: Problem solved: I didn't realize there is another copy of win32def.h in include files path, which has the same #ifdef guard but doesn't define my_tchar. Found it by changing the #ifdef then compiler complains things in another copy of win32def.h.

Comment: @user891260 delete / mark as solved Q then. Btw typedefs are evil, especially in hands of C newbies. Avoid them unless you really **want** to hide some implementation detail.
You may think it makes stuff easier to read or easier to maintain, but it generally does not (look for some reason why to, instead of why not). **struct rb_tree *node** gives you much more info about what object is than some kind of **Tree *Node** (pretty bad example but still...).

Comment: @AoeAoe I am not declaring a struct but just giving an alias for writing cross-platform code. What would a non C newbie do in that case then?

Comment: @user891260 no flame intended.